# Spivak Calculus, Ch 10, problem 32b: Can we use Leibniz's formula to calculate $f^{(k)}(x)$ if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, factorial

Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 10 on Differentiation, problem 32:

> 32. What is $f^{(k)}(x)$ if
>
> a)$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-1)^n}$
>
> *b) $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$

**My question regards part $b)$.**

$a)$ can be solved quite easily if you use the conclusion of a previous problem (30), which shows

> If $f(x)=x^{-n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then
>
> $$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}x^{-n-k}\tag{1}$$

$$g(x)=f(x+1)=x^{-n}$$

$$g^{(k)}(x)=f^{(k)}(x+1)=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}x^{-n-k}$$

$$g^{(k)}(x-1)=f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{d^{k} \frac{1}{(x-1)^n}}{dx^k}=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}(x-1)^{-n-k}\tag{2}$$

Similarly, we can show that

$$\frac{d^k \frac{1}{(x+1)^n}}{dx^k}=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}(x+1)^{-n-k}\tag{3}$$

**Now for part b).**

We can rewrite $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ in two different ways:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}\cdot \frac{1}{x-1}\tag{4}$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1} \right )\tag{5}$$

Spivak's solution manual differentiates $(5)$.

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{d^k \frac{1}{(x-1)^n}}{dx^k} - \frac{d^k \frac{1}{(x+1)^n}}{dx^k} \right )$$

So we can just sub in $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}((x-1)^{-n-k}-(x+1)^{-n-k})\tag{6}$$

**My question is: can we apply Leibniz's formula to differentiate $(4)$?**

Leibniz's formula tells us that

$$(f \cdot g)^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x) \cdot g^{(n-k)}(x)$$

If we apply this to $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}\cdot \frac{1}{x-1}$ then we get

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \left [(-1)^k \frac{k!}{0!}(x-1)^{-1-k} \right ] \left [(-1)^{n-k} \frac{(n+k)!}{0!}(x+1)^{-1-k}  \right ]$$

$$= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^nk! (n+k)! (x^2-1)^{-1-k}\tag{7}$$

Differentiating the sum in $(5)$ was the easier route. But is the calculation of differentiating $(4)$ correct? Is one route better than the other?

Comment: Leibniz' rule is the product rule, right? Then the answer is yes, you can always use Leibniz' rule in situations where you are allowed to use Leibniz' rule [ in other words, the function must be differentiable, and you must make sure you are working in the domain of the function]. But yes this is just two different methods for the same calculation. Try it for small values of $n$ yourself. As long as your calculations for arriving at $(7)$ are correct, there shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: And if there is a discrepancy between the two solutions then that means that in one of the methods, the conditions to use that method are not met [The alternative is that one of the *methods* themselves are faulty, which is absurd or ground-breaking].

Answer (score 2):

The calculation can be done in both ways. On the one hand we have

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f^{(k)}(x)}&=\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)^{(k)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{(k)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left((x-1)^{-1}\right)^{(k)}-\left((x+1)^{-1}\right)^{(k)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)(-2)\cdots(-1-(k-1))(x-1)^{-1-k}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.-(-1)(-2)\cdots(-1-(k-1))(x+1)^{-1-k}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)^kk!(x-1)^{-1-k}-(-1)^kk!(x+1)^{k+1}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k+1}}\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

On the other hand using the *[general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)* we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f^{(k)}(x)}&=\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)^{(k)}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{(k)}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{(j)}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{(k-j)}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\frac{(-1)^jj!}{(x-1)^{j+1}}\,\frac{(-1)^{k-j}(k-j)!}{(x+1)^{k-j+1}}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x+1)^{k-1}}\,\frac{1}{x-1}\sum_{j=0}^k\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^j\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x+1)^{k-1}}\,\frac{1}{x-1}\,\frac{1-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{k+1}}{1-\frac{x+1}{x-1}}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x+1)^{k-1}}\,\frac{1-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{k+1}}{-2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k+1}}\right)}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (1).

Obviously the first way is more convenient, since we obtain immediately the closed form (1). In (2) we have to cope with a sum and to apply the formula for *[finite geometric sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula)* till we finally obtain the same form as in (1).